# ESAPI Symmetric Encryption using JavaEncryptor

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption-symmetric, esapi

I am testing basic stuff in ESAPI, and I ran across [this symmetric encryption tutorial](https://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/esapi4java-core-2.0-symmetric-crypto-user-guide.html) and copied and pasted the code, (along with importing the ESAPI 2.1.0 jar file, ESAPI.properties and validation.properties in the 'src' directory in Eclipse)

Modified code from the tutorial:

```
import org.owasp.esapi.crypto.CipherText;
import org.owasp.esapi.crypto.PlainText;
import org.owasp.esapi.errors.EncryptionException;
import org.owasp.esapi.reference.crypto.JavaEncryptor;

public class ESAPIsymEncTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws EncryptionException{
    
        String myplaintext = "My plaintext";
        
            CipherText ciphertext =
                    JavaEncryptor.getInstance().encrypt( new PlainText(myplaintext) );
        PlainText recoveredPlaintext = JavaEncryptor.getInstance().decrypt(ciphertext);
            assert myplaintext.equals( recoveredPlaintext.toString() );
            
            System.out.println("recovered plaintext: " + recoveredPlaintext.toString());
    }
}
```

However, when I run this in Eclipse Luna using Java 1.8, I get this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.owasp.esapi.errors.EncryptionException: Encryption failure: Invalid key exception.
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.crypto.JavaEncryptor.encrypt(JavaEncryptor.java:526)
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.crypto.JavaEncryptor.encrypt(JavaEncryptor.java:338)
at com.fate.engine.test.ESAPIsymEncTester.main(ESAPIsymEncTester.java:15)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 96 bytes
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineGetKeySize(AESCipher.java:495)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.passCryptoPermCheck(Cipher.java:1062)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1033)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1367)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1301)
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.crypto.JavaEncryptor.encrypt(JavaEncryptor.java:504)
... 2 more
```

I am not sure if this is a bug in the JavaEncryptor.java code, or if I am pulling something that I misconfigured from the ESAPI.properties file.

I replaced the master key and salt by running the JavaEncryptor and copy/pasting the resultant key/salt.

If it is a bug, I will email the ESAPI guys to get clarification on how I can fix it, since I looked through the JavaEncryptor code and am not entirely clear where all of the pieces are coming from.

> Encryptor.MasterKey=WppLubGgsc/p6HhvcPf2LA==
>
> Encryptor.MasterSalt=YokRN9mjMUTZspEbzBY90NA6EC8=
>
> Encryptor.PreferredJCEProvider=
>
> Encryptor.EncryptionAlgorithm=AES
>
> Encryptor.CipherTransformation=AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
>
> Encryptor.cipher_modes.combined_modes=GCM,CCM,IAPM,EAX,OCB,CWC
>
> Encryptor.cipher_modes.additional_allowed=CBC
>
> Encryptor.EncryptionKeyLength=128
>
> Encryptor.ChooseIVMethod=random
>
> Encryptor.fixedIV=0x000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f
>
> Encryptor.CipherText.useMAC=true
>
> Encryptor.PlainText.overwrite=true
>
> Encryptor.HashAlgorithm=SHA-512   *****
>
> Encryptor.HashIterations=1024
>
> Encryptor.DigitalSignatureAlgorithm=SHA1withDSA
>
> Encryptor.DigitalSignatureKeyLength=1024
>
> Encryptor.RandomAlgorithm=SHA1PRNG
>
> Encryptor.CharacterEncoding=UTF-8
>
> Encryptor.KDF.PRF=HmacSHA1   *****

Comment: Added the Encryptor settings from esapi.properties. The stars are ones that I tweaked at some point in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to place the most important part of your log into the question:

```
Dec 11, 2015 8:05:24 AM org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory$JavaLogger log
WARNING: [SECURITY FAILURE Anonymous:null@unknown -> /JavaEncryptor] Encryption key length mismatch. ESAPI.EncryptionKeyLength is 128 bits, but length of actual encryption key is 24 bits.  Did you remember to regenerate your master key (if that is what you are using)???
```

This is a clue that there is something here that the library expects you to do.

It seems to me that you probably have the default encryptor properties set like this in `esapi.properties`:

```
Encryptor.MasterKey=owasp1
Encryptor.MasterSalt=testtest
```

The class `JavaEncryptor` has a main method that will generate valid properties for you.  Run it in eclipse or via the command line.  It will give you values to replace in `esapi.properties`, like this:

```
Dec 11, 2015 8:10:25 AM org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory$JavaLogger log
OFF: [SECURITY AUDIT Anonymous:null@unknown -> /SecurityProviderLoader] No Encryptor.PreferredJCEProvider specified.
SecurityConfiguration for Encryptor.EncryptionKeyLength not an integer in ESAPI.properties. Using default: 128
Generating a new secret master key
    use '-print' to also show available crypto algorithms from all the security providers
SecurityConfiguration for Encryptor.EncryptionKeyLength not an integer in ESAPI.properties. Using default: 128

Copy and paste these lines into your ESAPI.properties

#==============================================================
Encryptor.MasterKey=qW0Qw+8eb1Zu1MBv5djwqA==
Encryptor.MasterSalt=b0VappFU1Hd6LjIt+TGYqQlfrdU=
#==============================================================
```

Once I did that, your code example runs just fine.

Comment: I don't have the logger working at the moment, so I am just dumping traces to the console in Eclipse, but the MasterKey and MasterSalt are exactly (in format) like you have output from running the JavaEncryptor main.  The fact that you have it running though means that I have something in esapi.properties messed up.

I just need to find it now.

Comment: Make sure you don't have the master key and master salt entered twice.

Comment: I do not have two MasterKey/MasterSalts, so something else is at work.   I'll keep pecking away at it, as I have time.  Any further ideas are always welcome to direct my peckings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm going to suggest... grab the ***TEST*** version of ESAPI.properties from GitHub ("wget https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/master/src/test/resources/esapi/ESAPI.properties" should work, you use 'git' or save if from your browser), put it in place, and first use it AS-IS. If it fails, then there is a problem in you tweaked code. If it works, there was a problem in your ESAPI.properties file. Many people already suggested what to look for in terms of what might be wrong, but the differences should be minor enough that you should be able to spot them by diff'ing yours versus the TEST version in src/test/resources/esapi/ESAPI.properties. (The production version, incidentally, is under 'configuration/esapi/ESAPI.properties' and is not included with the jar because of some bug in the pom.xml which I don't know how to fix as I am not a Maven guru.)

If you have further questions, contact me at my Gmail account which you should be able to find easily enough via Google with my name and the term "OWASP". Once we figure out an answer that works for you, either you or I can post an answer back to Stack Overflow, but I don't frequent this forum enough to regularly monitor it. (Although, come to think of it, I probably do get notified of replies.)

Hope this helps,

-kevin w. wall / ESAPI crypto developer and co-project lead

Comment: Yea, that was my next step too.  Was to rebuild a raw test environment.  I was testing this within my broader project in the test subsection, but that is not a viable test environment since I have tweaked more places in the esapi.properties than I remember.  I am on the esapi dev/users mail list too as vanland.  I think I will diff the files first on our server, and see what I changed over the past few months.